# Asterisk behind NAT sets wrong Contact Header

Tags: nat, asterisk, voip, sip

I'm using SIP with asterisk 13.1.0 behind a statically configured NAT.
The servers private_ip differs from the public_ip, where I can reach it.
I've already set these options in the `sip.conf` file.

```
externaddr=public_ip:5060
media_address=public_ip
localnet=private_ip/24
```

If I now try to start a call, the messages work probably until the server sends the `OK` message to the client. In this message asterisk sets the `Contact` header to its private and not the public ip.

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK
From: "Test799" <sip:799@HOSTNAME>;tag=7ajcnltflq
To: <sip:62@HOSTNAME;user=phone>;tag=as08a05471
Call-ID: 54b6479ed3e3-io8z54pk25ve
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Session-Expires: 1800;refresher=uas
Contact: <sip:62@PRIVATE_IP:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Require: timer
Content-Length: ...

v=0
o=root 1234 1234 IN IP4 PUBLIC_IP
c=IN IP4 PUBLIC_IP
...
```

The UA now sends the following `ACK` to the PRIVATE_IP, because of the Contact header.

What is wrong with my configuration? Is this a bug in asterisk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this problem, if you use a IPv4 externaddr in combination with the IPv6 bindaddr setting.

```
;  c) Listen on the IPv4 wildcard.            Example: bindaddr=0.0.0.0
;  d) Listen on the IPv4 and IPv6 wildcards.  Example: bindaddr=::
...
; (Note that using bindaddr=:: will show only a single IPv6 socket in netstat.
;  IPv4 is supported at the same time using IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses.)
```

It is important to know that **bindaddr=::** does not bind on IPv4 wildcard.
It binds on IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses!